# Referencing JavaDoc and System Documentation

Tags: java, documentation

I have Spring MVC App in bootstrap, and am building my documentation for users of the app to reference. I am using Eclipse for developing and deploying my app on Tomcat.

How do I make the Javadoc and other documentation I am writing available to users of the app?

Would I need to build a separate JSP containing the links to all the docs? That seems like it would be cumbersome and time consuming.

Comment: Step 1: Generate the javadoc from the Java source files. --- Step 2: Include the generated javadoc HTML files in the jar/war file created for your Spring MVC App. --- 3) Start with that and see if the javadoc is now available as part of the webapp. Then ... --- 4) Add whatever links you deem necessary for the user to navigate to the javadoc pages.

Comment: Great, thank you very much. I'll give it a whirl...

Comment: Hi.... I think I am missing something. I have deployed the JavaDoc inside my WAR file, registered the folder in the MVC configuration, assigned permissions in Spring security, however I still get a 404 error. I am thinking maybe I need a Controller to manage the documentation ?? Any help is appreciated. Thanks !!

Comment: Without seeing what you've done, can't help you figure out what you did wrong.

Comment: @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception 
    {
      http.csrf().disable()
         .authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**", "/webjars/**", "/assets/**", "/doc/**").permitAll()

Comment: Don't show code in a comment. **Edit** the question to clarify it.